# Datagrid won't enter edit mode

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Is there a tutorial for how to use edit mode on a wpf datagrid? This simple grid below can't seem to edit the comment column.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="_myDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False">
            <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding doorNumber}" />
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="40" />
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Comment" MinWidth="100" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding doorComment}" ToolTip="{Binding doorComment}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding doorComment}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Why `IsReadOnly="True"` if you want it editable?

Comment: Cause I'm not very smart? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change IsReadOnly="True" to
IsReadOnly = "False"